# How to manage multiple independent containers

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am using Kubernetes for a number of microservices/apps but...

...if I want to setup, e.g. 20 independent Linux mail servers, all with their own public IPs but otherwise largely identical configuration, then Docker is a good fit (for consistent builds/deployments and also dealing with dead containers/restarts) but it doesn't seem right to create 20 deployments, 20 LB services etc. to achieve this. This would also clutter up my CI/CD tool with 20 projects for the 20 deployments since they wouldn't just be 20 instances of the same thing.

What do people think is a good tool for consistent server deployments, so that if I wanted to increase from e.g. 20 to 30 servers, I could automate it as much as possible.

(We could use Azure or Amazon as well as Kubernetes so we have some flexibility)

Comment: [Helm](https://helm.sh) is a reasonably standard tool that allows templating in the Kubernetes YAML files, so you could stamp out a couple dozen mostly-identical copies of the same Kubernetes objects.  There are other tools that fill a similar need.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, you can get away with a single Helm chart that captures the essence of your mail server deployment and then a single `values.yaml` per instance. Deployment is just running `helm upgrade --install` in a `for` loop.

If you need more, you can look at creating an Operator for your own use:

- a `MailServer` Custom Resource Definition (CRD) that captures all the configuration about a mail server instance
- an Operator that reacts to CRUD operations on `MailServer` resources and respectively deploys, redeploys or undeploys. The initial implementation can simply be a small Kopf daemon managing the Helm chart from above.